# Need help explaining bit manipulation with / and % in wiss code

Tags: c, bitmap, bit-manipulation

```
setbit(mapptr, pos)
register unsigned char  *mapptr;
register int    pos;
{
/* adjust word pointer and bit offset (pos) */

    /************** FROM HERE ****************/
    mapptr += pos / BITSPERBYTE;
    pos %= BITSPERBYTE;
    /*************** TO HERE ***************/

*mapptr |= 1 << pos;        /* set bit */
 }
```

There is bit manipulation code in wiss filesystem I don't understand (marked with a pair of comments).

Why do divide the `pos` into `BITPERBYTE` (defined as `8`) and operate the `pos` into `BITPERBYTE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code "packs" bits into bytes in such a way that bits 0..7 go into byte 0, 8..15 go into byte 1, 16..23 go into byte 2, and so on. If you divide a bit number by 8 and drop the remainder, you will end up with the corresponding byte number:

```
int byteNumber = bitNumber / BITSPERBYTE;
```

Your code snippet adds `byteNumber` to `mapptr`, which amounts to indexing an array of bytes through pointer arithmetic.

The result of `% 8` is the same as obtaining these last three bits, i.e. a number from 0 to 7, inclusive. This is the bit number within the corresponding byte:

```
int bitInByte = bitNumber % BITSPERBYTE;
```

The result of `%` is always in the range `0..BITSPERBYTE-1`.

**Note:** Your code is pre-ANSI, consider rewriting it using the syntax that has been standard for the last few decades, and change the type of `pos` to `unsigned`:

```
void setbit(unsigned char *mapptr, unsigned int pos) {
    mapptr += pos / BITSPERBYTE;
    pos %= BITSPERBYTE;
    *mapptr |= 1 << pos;
}
```

Comment: "The result of % 8 is the same as obtaining these last three bits" is only true when `pos >= 0`.  Similar for `/8` If negative values of `pos` are possible, code would be better off using `&7` and `>>3`.  Otherwise `pos` should be `unsigned`.

Comment: @chux Thanks for the comment! I think the `pos` should be `unsigned` in this code (although the actual answer depends on the meaning of `mapptr`).

Answer (score 1):

You want to set bit X in a bitmap. If there are eight bits in a byte,

- bit X will lie in byte `X/8` (0-based, integer maths => rounded towards zero, i.e. rounded down for positive `pos`)
- it will be the `X%8` th bit of that byte (i.e. removing the component we used to find the byte in this computation)

so

```
mapptr += pos / BITSPERBYTE;
```

computes the byte offset of the bit we want to set, adding it to the pointer, and

```
pos %= BITSPERBYTE;
```

modified `pos` to index the bit with that byte that we want to set; then `1 << pos` generates that bit, and we 'or' it into the byte we've picked:

```
*mapptr |= 1 << pos;        /* set bit */
```

Comment: "integer maths => rounded down" is only true when `x >= 0`, else `x/8` is round up.  (truncate).

Comment: @chux True, but using a negative pos 1) wouldn't really make sense as a bit offset, although it is allowed by the function signature 2) would be broken in this function in that case. But good point, I'll edit.